# Update list in Python class using a for loop

Tags: python, list, class, oop

If I have a Python class that includes a list, what is the best way to update that list inside a for loop?

For example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

    def does_not_work(self):
        for value in self.values:
            value += 1

    def this_works(self):
        for i, value in enumerate(self.values):
            self.values[i] += 1

    def works_too(self):
        new_values = []
        for value in self.values:
            value += 1
            new_values.append(value)
        self.values = new_values


t = Test()
print t.values
>> [ 1, 2, 3 ]

t.does_not_work()
print t.values
>> [ 1, 2, 3 ]

t.this_works()
print t.values
>> [ 2, 3, 4 ]

t.works_too()
print t.values
>> [ 3, 4, 5 ]
```

- Option #1: updating values in the list don't "stick," so this is clearly not the right approach
- Option #2: works as intended but requires `enumerate()`
- Option #3: uses the simpler for-loop syntax but requires re-building the list

I'm sure there are lots of other ways that work (fancy list-comprehension methods, etc) too but am interested in readability/clarity over conciseness.

Note: there are quite a few questions that seem to hint at this but (from what I found) most are wrapped in project code or specific problems – I'm looking for a general best-practices answer.

Comment: An `int` is immutable. `value += 1` just changes what the local variable `value` refers to, then discards that object when `value` is next assigned by the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` value is immutable.

In Option 1, `value += 1` simply assigns the name `value` to a new object, without changing anything about the object already in `self.values`.

In Option 2, you are modifying the *list* to refer to a new value, not the existing value.

In Option 3, you are creating a new list, then changing `self.value` to refer to that list.

In none of the three options are you changing any of the existing values in `self.values`.

---

I would probably just create a new list with a list comprehension:

```
self.values = [x + 1 for x in self.values]
```

though if you want to avoid creating a new list, you can use slice assignment to reassign to each element of the existing list.

```
self.values[:] = (x + 1 for x in self.values)
```

Comment: Thanks – it's odd/confusing since Option #1 works as expected in Java but not in Python, which is where my confusing came from originally. In my particular case, list comprehension isn't a good option because I need to do a lot of processing inside the loop.

Comment: My Java knowledge is woefully out of date, but as I recall, you can't store a primitive (and immutable) `int` value in a container, only mutable `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 1):

this is nice:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] += sth
```

Comment: Yeah, I have that above in my question – was wondering if there's a more elegant way (but seems like not)